# OneDrive auto login after initial authorisation

Tags: c#, authentication, onedrive

I want to be able login user automatically in my WPF C# app after he/she accepts it and login manually for the first time. Currently my code to login using prompt window works:

```
try
{
    _msaAuthenticationProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider("XXXX",
        "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf", new[] {"onedrive.readonly", "wl.signin", "wl.offline_access" });
    await _msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
    _oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0", _msaAuthenticationProvider);

    Item item = await _oneDriveClient
        .Drive
        .Root
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();

    Print("Logged in as " + item.CreatedBy.User.DisplayName);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    PresentServiceException(exc);
}
```

Now the question is how do I save some info (tokens maybe?) and use them next time my app is launched to log in a specific user without showing that prompt window? I've read about `GetSilentlyAuthenticatedMicrosoftAccountClient` method on `OneDriveClient` but it seems not to be included in Microsoft.OneDrive.SDK 2.0.0 (all samples that use this and `OneDriveClientExtensions` reference to SDK in version 1.1.5). Do you have any idea how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

// your code

```
_msaAuthenticationProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider("XXXX", "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf", new[] {"onedrive.readonly", "wl.signin", "wl.offline_access" });
await _msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
_oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0", _msaAuthenticationProvider);
await _msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
```

// add this
// save refresh token

```
var refreshtoken = (((MsaAuthenticationProvider)oneDriveClient.AuthenticationProvider).CurrentAccountSession).RefreshToken;
```

// store this refresh token secure between sessions.
 // ------------------------------------
// later, if you want to connect to OneDrive, create AccountSession and use that stored  RefreshToken

```
AccountSession session = new AccountSession();
session.ClientId = <<your id>>; // your "XXXX"
session.RefreshToken = refreshtoken;
_msaAuthenticationProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider(....
_oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient(....
_msaAuthenticationProvider.CurrentAccountSession = session;
await _msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
```

Comment: You should explain your solution a little.

Comment: Thanks, that solution actually made it work. Too bad it isn't described in documentation. I've tried something similar. I've copied whole 'AccountSession' object instead of 'refreshToken'. Can you tell me what is proper way to store that token when my app is closed that would be secure?

Comment: Hi, I use PasswordVault class for secure storing.

Comment: @tweant - an example of stgoring that rerfesh token
`var vault = new PasswordVault();
var cred = new PasswordCredential("resource", "userName", refreshtoken);
vault.Add(cred);`

Comment: @user6741253, What to do if RefreshToken is expired? Or `_msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync()` will require new token automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this was available in the previous version of the SDK. When it was refactored for v2, not quite all of the authentication mechanisms were re-implemented. I have opened a Github issue to deal with this. https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-dotnet-msa-auth-adapter/issues/7